# Where can I get the complete English translations of the Sri Krishna Chaitanya Charitamritam & Sri Chaitanya Charitamritam Mahakavyam?

Tags: translation-request, chaitanya

I would like to read the Sri Chaitanya Charitamritam Mahakavyam by Kavi Karnapura and the Sri Krishna Chaitanya Charitamritam by Murari Gupta in English. Can anyone provide me some links for these biographies?

Comment: Did you try ISKCON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read Kavi Karnapura's Chaitanya Charita Mahakavya in English [here](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Kavi-Karnapura/Kavi_Karnapura_Sri_Caitanya_Carita.pdf).  And you can read Murari Gupta's Krishna Chaitanya Charitamrita [here](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Murari-Gupta/Murari_Gupta_Sri_Krsna_Caitanya_Carita_Maha_Kavya.pdf).

Comment: The Mahavakya link is http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Kavi-Karnapura/Kavi_Karnapura_Sri_Caitanya_Carita.pdf and the Charitamrita link is http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Murari-Gupta/Murari_Gupta_Sri_Krsna_Caitanya_Carita_Maha_Kavya.pdf . I think you have interchanged the order of the links.