# Did Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu also write a Shivashtakam?

Tags: shiva, identification-request, stotra, chaitanya

I have seen in atleast three places saying that he has written a Shivashtakam (apart from the one by Sri Adi Shankaracharya). 
1. [backtogodhead](http://www.backtogodhead.in/sri-sivastakam-by-nanda-gopal-jivana-dasa/) (cites the source "Recorded in Murari Gupta’s Sri Caitanya Carita Mahakavya") 
2. [saivism.net](https://www.saivism.net/prayers/shivashtakam.asp)

3. [hindupedia.com](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Shivashtakam#Shivashtakam_by_Chaitanya_Mahaprabhu)

But Srila Prabhupada, in Teachings of Lord Chaitanya, says -

> "Although Lord Caitanya was widely renowned as a scholar in His youth, He left only eight verses, called Śikṣāṣṭaka.”

This Shivashtakam is different from the popular one which starts from "Prabhum Prananaatham..." by Adi Shankaracharya.

EDIT : I have found the Murari Gupta's Sri Chaitanya Carita Mahakavya here - [Where can I get the complete English translations of the Sri Krishna Chaitanya Charitamritam & Sri Chaitanya Charitamritam Mahakavyam?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20296/where-can-i-get-the-complete-english-translations-of-the-sri-krishna-chaitanya-c?rq=1) . The link is http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Murari-Gupta/Murari_Gupta_Sri_Krsna_Caitanya_Carita_Maha_Kavya.pdf . If someone could locate the Shivashtakam here, as cited in backtogodhead.in, it would be a great favour.

Comment: It could be that in relation to Gaudiya Vaishnavite siddhanta, he left only 8 verses.

Comment: The Hindupedia link says that he did. So what more confirmation do you want? If your question did not contain that Hindupedia link for example then using it one of us could have answered it.

Comment: @Rickross, Srila Prabhupada belongs to Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's sampradaya, Gaudiya Vaishnava, and he says that He only wrote Siksastaka. Also I feel that if an incarnation of Lord Sri Krishna wrote an Ashtakam glorifying Lord Shiva it would be far more popular but I only see the one by Sri Shankaracharya recorded. So I want confirmation that these websites haven't picked up an independent work and misattributed it to Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu.

Comment: It is not Shivashtakam... It is Shikshashtakam, which is the essence of Lord Caitanya’s teachings, or ‘Shiksha’...

Comment: @Rickross Actually, most of the Gaudiya vaishnava acharyas wrote that Chaitanya left only Siksastaka. If this Shivashtakam was written by Chaitanya then why Prabhupada and others would hide it? What do you think about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Shivastakam can be found in 8th sarga, page 287 of  [Sri Krishna Chaitanya Charita Mahakavya](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Murari-Gupta/Murari_Gupta_Sri_Krsna_Caitanya_Carita_Maha_Kavya.pdf). It was originally composed by Mahaprabhu himself.

These are the prayers offered by Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu when he took darshan of Lord Shiva (seems to be Lingaraj temple) in Bhubhaneshwar.

There were few devotees going with him and they were noted down by devotees. These prayers were spoken by mahaprabhu but not written down by Chaitanya Mahaprabhu.

It is similar to [61 explanations](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/24) of [atma rama verse](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/7/10), this was spoken by Mahaprabhu and recorded by others.

Shiksastakam are the verses which seems to be written by Chaitanya Mahaprabhu himself:

> [CC 3.20.64](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/antya/20/64): The Lord had formerly composed these eight verses to teach people in general. Now He personally tasted the meaning of the verses, which are called the Siksasṭaka.

Comment: If he didn't write this version of Shivashtakam, then who did?

Comment: Also, what do you mean when you say that it is similar to the 61 explanations of the atma rama verse. I think those explanations were originally conceived by Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu, but are you saying that he repeated them, having received them from somewhere else?

Comment: @TigerShroff what I meant is that he didn't pen them down on his own. He just spoke and others recorded it. Shiksastakam is the only work Chaitanya mahaprabhu penned down and actually wrote them somewhere.

Comment: So this prayer is originally composed by Him (but not explicitly written down by Him)?

Comment: @TigerShroff yes this is what I meant. Otherwise there are many sections in Chaitanya charitamrta like I pointed out one above,  conceived by Chaitanya mahaprabhu himself.

Comment: @TigerShroff You can upvote the answer if that is helpful. Upvoting answers is a good sign and increases interest to contribute more.

Comment: "8th sarga, page 287" of Chaitanya charitamritam?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, Just out of curiousity, how do you know that I didn't upvote it? Maybe I had upvoted and someone else downvoted the answer, so it was at 0 points. By the way, I was reminded to upvote due to your comment, so thanks.

Comment: @TigerShroff When you reach a reputation of 750, you can look at vote counts. It showed no upvotes and downvotes. So, it was easy. You can have a look at all the privileges in the [help center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Comment: @KrishnaShweta no from murari gupta Sri Krishna Chaitanya maha kavya whose url is given in the question

Comment: Please edit your answer and write "yes, Chaitanya also wrote... is mentioned in..." something like that :)

Comment: @KrishnaShweta I am avoiding write word, I edited saying they were spoken by mahaprabhu.