# Where can I find a sanskrit text version of Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's Shivashtakam?

Tags: shiva, chaitanya

Where can I find Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's Shivashtakam rendered in Sanskrit? Can someone on this website do it as a huge favour? I want to chant it but can't be sure of the pronounciation since the places I have found it are all in Roman letters, and that too plain Roman letters, without accurate transliteration.

As this question discusses - [Did Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu also write a Shivashtakam?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29775/did-sri-chaitanya-mahaprabhu-also-write-a-shivashtakam/29901?noredirect=1#comment90790_29901) - Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu did write a Shivashtakam, for those who didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is available with accurate Roman transliteration in page 287 and 288 of [Sri Krishna Chaitanya charita maha kavyam](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Murari-Gupta/Murari_Gupta_Sri_Krsna_Caitanya_Carita_Maha_Kavya.pdf)

Comment: Can you quote it from there and post it in the answer for the sake of completeness? I can't download the pdf at the moment.

Comment: Okay, the way the pdf is formatted it is hard to copy the text. You have told me where to find it. Thanks a lot! I'll type up the Shivashtakam at a later date and post it in the question itself.

Comment: @TigerShroff you can instead add an answer to your question with sanskrit text once you complete typing it.